# how to picking up the min date only one line in the table by Group by

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT SYSDATE date_1,'1' data_1 ,1 item FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,7) date_1,'8'data, '1' item_ FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,6)+ 10, '4' data, '1' item FROM dual
UNION
SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,6) date_1,'3' data, '2' item FROM DUAL
)
SELECT min(date_1), data,item
FROM a 
WHERE date_1 BETWEEN add_months(SYSDATE,6) AND last_day(add_months(SYSDATE,7))
GROUP BY item,data
```

the result show that item 1 has two lines, but I only want the min date one, how to change the code to display one data for one item at min(date).
**and i need the date match the right data and item **.
thank you for reading and look forward for right answer.

i find a not good way to invoke what i mean: group by item  and select the min date_1 in the scope

```
WITH A AS (
      SELECT SYSDATE date_1,               '1' data, '1' item FROM DUAL
UNION SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,7) date_1, '8' data, '1' item FROM DUAL
UNION SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,6)+ 10,    '4' data, '1' item FROM dual
UNION SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,6) date_1, '3' data, '2' item FROM DUAL
)   
select a.* from A a,(select min(date_1) date_1,item  from A
where 
date_1 BETWEEN add_months(SYSDATE, 6) 
                 AND last_day(add_months(SYSDATE, 7))
                 group by item) b where a.date_1 = b.date_1 and a.item= b.item
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`KEEP ... FIRST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm#i1000901):

```
SQL> WITH A AS (
  2        SELECT SYSDATE date_1,               '1' data, '1' item FROM DUAL
  3  UNION SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,7) date_1, '8' data, '1' item FROM DUAL
  4  UNION SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,6)+ 10,    '4' data, '1' item FROM dual
  5  UNION SELECT add_months(SYSDATE,6) date_1, '3' data, '2' item FROM DUAL
  6  )
  7  SELECT MIN(date_1), item,
  8         MAX(data) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_1) DATA
  9    FROM a
 10   WHERE date_1 BETWEEN add_months(SYSDATE, 6)
 11                    AND last_day(add_months(SYSDATE, 7))
 12   GROUP BY item;

MIN(DATE_1) ITEM DATA
----------- ---- ----
01/06/2013  1    4
22/05/2013  2    3
```

This will select the (MAX) data on the subset of row that has the lowest date (here only one row).

Comment: use `MAX(data) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_1) DATA` seems work well now, but i don't know what it means.

Comment: I included a link to the doc in my answer: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm#i1000901 . It means: "instead of using the MAX function on the whole GROUP, apply the function only on the rows that have the lowest DATE (=`FIRST ORDER BY date_1`)"